# why outlook has access denied with dcomcnfg identity setting to specific user

Tags: c#, outlook, dcom

Im wrote my own service-application to send entries into the calendar from outlook.
In general, this is working well since 10 years.

The only thing i have to do was in dcomcfng, selecting the outlook message object, an change the
running identity to an specific user and he has installed/configured outlook correctly.
Everthing works fine as service.

Now my problem... :-)

A customer has become some new computer, and setting up outlook correctly.
Now im going to dcomcnfg, change the identity from interactiv to that specific user.
But on execution, my service had no rights(access denied) for that outlook-object.

Now i'm logged in into windows with this specific user (user : "Work101")
Then i start an test-application, as normal exe file (not as service) and i receive the same error.
Access deniend

If i change the identity in dcom to "interactive user", my test-application works fine.
(which is User Work101)

If i change the identity in dcom to "executing user", my test-application works fine.
(which is User Work101)

But if i set this user "work101" in dcom identity as specific user, i got "access denied".
There is no other user like this, no writing misstake, no password misstakes...everthing is written correct.

Does someone know where is the problem, that the speicific user has no access, but the same user works fine
if the identity is set to "interactive user" or "executing user" ?

I checked registry, repair office 365, restarting machine and and and. nothing works.

on my virtual machine i setting up the same type of windows, installing office, changed dcom and it runs
without problem.

i dont get it -.-

the Test-app was written with direct calling the outlook.application,
and also tryed with interop-functions. there was no difference on this strange computer.

@edit

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM" Guid="{1B562E86-B7AA-4131-BADC-B6F3A001407E}" EventSourceName="DCOM" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">10000</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-08-21T14:06:47.3753088Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>22884</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{7c7f596d-3cd3-4cba-892b-8f6c7524d954}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="976" ThreadID="16368" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>VS-ADS02</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3793602545-3278945853-1181855047-1630" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE -Embedding</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">2147942405</Data> 
  <Data Name="param3">{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: _"But on execution, my service had no rights(access denied) for that outlook-object"_ - does your code report the exact security-principal that it's running under when it encounters issues? Have you performed any tracing of DCOM (via WMI) on both the working and non-working environments to spot-any-differences? Have you seen this article about recent changes to DCOM security in 2022? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/dcom-authentication-hardening-what-you-need-to-know/ba-p/3657154

Comment: Also, ...why on earth do you need to fiddle with DCOM _at all_? I've never needed to alter DCOM permissions to get Office COM interop applications to work - in fact, DCOM shouldn't come into play at all unless you're accessing an Outlook instance over the network...

Comment: which other solution works if i should have access to the outlook-calendar as service? if interacitve, executing user does not work if i would create some new outlook.application(). even on that if the service runs as this specific user. And it works on win7 to win 22 server.  but not on this customer-computer.

Comment: You should just be able to use Outlook's COM interface directly... may I ask _how_ your C# code is performing COM interop? Are you using VS's built-in interop assembly generation (and you have done a recent rebuild on a modern version of VS, right?) - or are you using a static copy of some DLLs from years ago?

Comment: @Dai i do it normaly with interop. the init is like this : Type OutlookType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");
               m_oOutlookApp = Activator.CreateInstance(OutlookType);             But i editet my application also to use the library direct with xy = new Outlook.Application() and other functions.  Its the same result, access denied.

Comment: Have you checked the various Windows event logs? As this is security-related you'll certainly find _something_ in the Security log, but hopefully others too.

Comment: Yes, in the logs is it. but there is no other information. dcom has user "xy\work101" blocked from start "c:\.......outlook.exe -embedded" return code 0x800.... access denied

Comment: Please copy the XML view of that logged-event (and any other relevant events) and paste it into your question - including the full Event Source and Event Id.

Comment: done. i created now a brand new user on that computer, set up office, everthing looks god in outlook. But i start now my test-application, windows gives me an message that the exchangeserver is not running. but if i start outlook, everything is correct. this computer makes me crazy -.-

Comment: Is the computer in an Active Directory domain or have some kind of Group Policy set-up?

Comment: yes, he is in a domain. the users(domain-users) has adminstration rights and dcom-user rights and and and. on the new user iv got some exception if i try to read the outlook-folder, which is meaning that the exchange-server is not available...network problems exist. ...dont know... maybe i try it on another computer. im ona giving up -.-